# Extension deployment tool

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Say I had the source for a chrome extension on github. Is there an easy way for someone to build and add it to their chrome browser?

I was hoping for the end user experience to be something like this:

```
git clone _somewhere_/awesomeExtension.git
something -install
```

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable method of adding unpacked extensions is through the `chrome://extensions` UI.

Comment: I have been seeing you here answering Chrome extensions questions from last two years. Great sir! We made a production extension with your great help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to install through GIT directly, but you can create a git branch in any drive and pull the source code. Then go to Chrome Extensions, enable Developer mode, then click load unpacked extension and route it to git folder. You are done, whenever you pull the latest code from GIT, go to chrome extensions tab and click update/refresh extension.